# copy data from sheet to sheet with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from sheet 2 to sheet 5 with multiple criteria. 
example data:

[image]

I wrote the following code ...

```
Dim myrange As Range

Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1:k50")

myrange.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

myrange.AutoFilter field:=1, criteria1:="=Monitors"
myrange.AutoFilter field:=2, criteria1:="=Jul-19"
myrange.AutoFilter field:=3, criteria1:="=1"
myrange.AutoFilter field:=5, criteria1:="=P"

myrange.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy

With Sheet5.Range("a10")
.PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Select
End With
myrange.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
```

When I run the code it copies headings only.

the output should be.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: if your headings are on row 2 I think you'll have to apply the filter to row 2.

Comment: if you change `myrange.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy` to `myrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` you only copy the part of the range which is visible after you've used autofilter.

Comment: i changed to 'myrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy'. it didn't go well. @Beek

Comment: @zozoz I'm not sure what you mean by "didn't go well". Do you get an error or are the results not what you expected?

Comment: Tqs for your reply. I changed to 'myrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy'. Only headings copied from sheet 2 to sheet 5. @Beek

Comment: @zozoz are you certain there are still visible rows (apart from headings) after your autofilter? That's the only problem I can think of, since I've tested mine and it works for me.

Comment: Great .. its working....@Beek

Answer (score 0):

I'd do in a slightly different way, as I'm not too into using filters in macros.
Please note this code will paste in Sheet5 last row. Feel free to adapt it to your needs.
Also, please note using dates (like "Jul-19") in this format could cause you some issues. Try to convert it (on the code below) to a value depending on your original table's format:

```
Sub testStackOverflow()
Dim myrange As Range
Dim Criteria1 As String
Dim Criteria2 As String
Dim Criteria3 As String
Dim Criteria4 As String

Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A50")


Criteria1 = "Monitors"
Criteria2 = "Jul-19"
Criteria3 = "1"
Criteria4 = "P"



For Each SearchCell In myrange
    Debug.Print SearchCell.Value
    If SearchCell.Value = Criteria1 Then
        If SearchCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Criteria2 Then
            If SearchCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Criteria3 Then
                If SearchCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Criteria4 Then
                    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & LastRow).Value = SearchCell.Value
                    Sheets("Sheet5").Range("B" & LastRow).Value = SearchCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    Sheets("Sheet5").Range("C" & LastRow).Value = SearchCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    Sheets("Sheet5").Range("D" & LastRow).Value = SearchCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    Sheets("Sheet5").Range("E" & LastRow).Value = SearchCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next SearchCell

End Sub
```